# how to use i18n with jolt client?

Tags: java, web-services, internationalization, request

I have a problem sending the euro sign within a jolt request. The server is set to use internationalization.
On the client side i did the folowing:

-the classpath contains jolti18n.jar and joltse.jar
-i set System.setProperty("bea.jolt.encoding", "ISO-8859-1"); this is the charset used on the server
-the connection is made using the parameter i18n=true

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: can you share your code. I think character set will not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no Euro sign in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), thus it could not be converted.

Please try setting encoding to UTF-8 instead.

Comment: @calin: in that case I don't understand this point: "i set System.setProperty("bea.jolt.encoding", "ISO-8859-1"); ". I thought you were setting it for the server, not the client?

Comment: it is for the client. Actually i haven't found an explanation on how to use i18n and this i've seen in another project(don't know if it works and i think it doesn't influence anything after tests).